# Four inscribed circles

Tags: geometry

In the following diagram, let the side length of the large square be $s$.

[image]

How do I specifically determine the numerical value of the area of the blue region?

I can easily show the equivalence between the blue and yellow area, but I don't think this helps determine the area. If possible, I would like to have a method without integration.

Comment: There are no values given in the diagram. How is it possible to determine the numerical value of any region of the diagram?

Comment: @Saksham See my edit.

Comment: if you make a jpeg of your diagram, perhaps as a screen capture or a photograph, that can be uploaded to this site.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you! I did as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Assume $s=1$.

The [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) says
$$
\left(\frac14\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sqrt2}4\right)^2+\left(\frac12\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}4\cdot\frac12\cos(GOI)
$$
thus, $\cos(GOI)=\frac58\sqrt2$. Furthermore,
$$
\left(\frac12\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sqrt2}4\right)^2+\left(\frac14\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}4\cdot\frac14\cos(OGI)
$$
thus, $\cos(CGI)=-\cos(OGI)=\frac14\sqrt2$

Using [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), the area of $\triangle OGI$ is
$$
\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt2}8\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt2}8\cdot\frac{-1+\sqrt2}8\cdot\frac{3-\sqrt2}8}=\frac{\sqrt7}{64}
$$

The area of one yellow lune is
$$
\overbrace{\left(\frac14\right)^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac14\sqrt2\right)}^{\text{wedge }IGJ}-\overbrace{\left(\frac12\right)^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac58\sqrt2\right)}^{\text{wedge }IOJ}+\overbrace{\ 2\cdot\frac{\sqrt7}{64}\ }^{2\triangle OGI}
$$
The area of the blue region is the area of the four yellow lunes ($\odot(O,OJ)=4\!\odot\!(G,GJ)$ and then we subtract $4$ white areas instead of $1$)
$$
\frac14\cos^{-1}\left(\frac14\sqrt2\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac58\sqrt2\right)+\frac{\sqrt7}8\,\dot=\,0.14638125953034782476
$$
For arbitrary $s$, multiply this result by $s^2$.

Comment: Your calculation of $|\triangle OGI|$ is not correct.  It should be $\sqrt{7}/64$.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the area of the triangle (again).  I think my answer is now correct.

Comment: Our answers now agree up to a scaling constant:  $0.585525 = 16(0.0365953)$.

Comment: @robjohn, can you please elaborate how did you find the area of yellow lune? I'm finding it difficult to understand.

Comment: @SarGe: I have added some explanatory text. Let me know if there are still questions.

Comment: @robjohn, I've doubt. 1. Does wedge means triangle? 2. If so, the area of one lune is coming to be $0$. 3. What does $\odot$ mean?

Comment: @SarGe: To compute the area of a lune, one would need to consider an area with some part of a circle. Note that the area of the "wedge" $IGJ$ is given as $\left(\frac14\right)^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac14\sqrt2\right)=|IG|^2\frac{\angle IGJ}2$, which is the area of the circular wedge. $\odot$ is a circle with a center.  Note that $O$ and $OJ$ are the center and radius of a circle. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: @SarGe: After some searching, I did find the circular wedge symbols $\unicode{x2aa6}$ and $\large\unicode{x2314}$, but they look too small and too much like triangles not to be confusing.

Comment: @robjohn, it is clear from the diagram that $\text{wedge}\;IGJ+2\triangle OGI=\text{wedge}\;IOJ$. So, area of one yellow lune is coming to be $0$. Please help.

Comment: @SarGe: Did you happen to notice that the radii of those wedges are different? Your equation does not hold.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to calculate the area of the four yellow lunes using something like http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lune.html for instance (which I've previously misread as simpler, sorry).

Comment: MathJax hints:  When you want the square root of  multicharacter thing, put it in braces to get the top bar to extend.  \sqrt{2r} gives $\sqrt {2r}$  To get stacked fractions, use \frac 54 to get $\frac 54$.  Again, if numerator or denominator is more than one character, put it in braces.  Exponents look nice, so 5r^2 gives $5r^2$

Comment: "the area of the lune of two circles of radii a and b separated by distance c is the same as an area of a triangle of sides a, b and c." This statement is only true when the diameter of the smaller circle starts and ends on the larger circle.

Comment: You are right, I misread the page. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality let the radius of the smaller circles be $1$, thus the larger circle has radius $2$.  Place the figure on a coordinate plane with $O$ at the origin.  Let the point of intersection $P(x,y)$ of $\odot G$ with $\odot O$ in the first quadrant with $x > y$ is given by the solution to the system $$\begin{align*} x^2 + y^2 &= 4, \\ (x-1)^2 +(y-1)^2 &= 1. \end{align*}$$  This is trivially solved; we first get $x + y = 5/2$, thus $$P(x,y) = (P_x, P_y) = \left(\frac{5 + \sqrt{7}}{4}, \frac{5 - \sqrt{7}}{4}\right).$$  The area of the white sliver region is therefore given by $$(2 - P_x) - \left(\frac{1}{2} 2^2 \tan^{-1} \frac{P_y}{P_x} - \frac{1}{2} P_x P_y \right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} 1^2 \tan^{-1} \frac{1 - P_y}{P_x - 1} - \frac{1}{2} (P_x - 1)(1 - P_y)\right).$$  Some careful but tedious algebra gives the result $$\frac{6-\sqrt{7}}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \frac{4-\sqrt{7}}{3} - 2 \tan^{-1} \frac{16-5\sqrt{7}}{9} \approx 0.0291402.$$  This value can also be found by evaluating $$\int_{x=(5+\sqrt{7})/4}^2 1 - \sqrt{2x-x^2} - \sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx.$$

Since the area of the white corner region is easily found to be $$1 - \frac{\pi}{4},$$ a single yellow area is simply $$3\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) - \left(\frac{6-\sqrt{7}}{2} - \tan^{-1} \frac{4-\sqrt{7}}{3} - 4 \tan^{-1} \frac{16-5\sqrt{7}}{9} \right).$$

The blue area can be obtained by integrating for half the area of one of the four peripheral sections, which is $$\int_{y=0}^{(5 - \sqrt{7})/4} \sqrt{4-y^2} - 1 - \sqrt{2y-y^2} \, dy.$$

Comment: Evaluating the formula you have for a single yellow area gives $0.585525$ which seems a bit large since it should be less than a quarter of the whole square. The integral evaluates to $0.1854616$ which is almost twice the answer I get. I have checked my answer, and I think it is correct.

Comment: @robjohn I have assumed a square of side length $4$.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the small circles to have radius $1$.  You have four lunes shaped as below.  Point $A$ is the center of a circle of radius $1$, located at $(\sqrt 2,0)$.  Point $B$, the center of the square in your diagram, is the center of a circle of radius $2$, located at $(0,0)$.  We draw $BC$, the vertical line through the intersections of the two circles.  The points $B$ and $C$ are at $(\frac 5{2\sqrt2},\pm \frac {\sqrt 7}{2 \sqrt 2})$  The area of the lune is the difference between the areas of two [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), $A=\frac{R^2}2(\theta-\sin \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the full angle subtended by the segment.  The small angle $\theta_1=2\arctan(\frac {\sqrt 7}5)\approx 0.9734$.  The large angle $\theta_2=2\arctan(\sqrt 7)\approx 2.4189$.  The  area of one lune is then about $0.294$

[image]

Comment: I follow this until the very last calculation, where I get the area as $\approx 0.5855$. Ready reckoner: the blue area is a bit less than 3 times the central part of the blue area, so a bit less than $3(4-\pi)\approx 2.575$, so one lune is a quarter of this which is a bit less than $\approx 0.6438$.